# Looping through a set range of email addresses and names to send an email depending on the pivot field

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to loop through a set of email addresses, where the "Example" refers to a specific email on another sheet and sends accordingly.

[image]

```vb
Sub EmailFund1()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection

    Range("B1").Select
    Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Format").ClearAllFilters
    Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Format").CurrentPage = "Example"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With r.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
        .To = "enteremailhere"
        .cc = ""
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "EnterSubjectHere"

        .Send

    End With
End Sub
```

I want to loop through the long list of fields in the pivot tables and send to specific email address depending on the selected filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    Sub EmailFund1()

        Dim r As Range
        Dim SItm As SlicerItem
        Dim SItm2 As SlicerItem
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim strEmail As String
        Dim strSubject As String
        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim intJ As Integer
        Dim objRow As Range
        Dim blnExit As Boolean

        Set r = Worksheets("Fund Pivot").Range("B1")
        r.Select

        For Each objRow In Worksheets("VBA Tab").Rows
            blnExit = False

            ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

            For Each SItm In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Fund_s").SlicerItems


                SItm.Selected = True
                For Each SItm2 In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Fund_s").SlicerItems
                    If SItm.Name <> SItm2.Name Then
                        SItm2.Selected = False
                    End If
                Next


                strEmail = LCase(Trim(objRow.Cells(, 2).Value))
                strSubject = UCase(Trim(objRow.Cells(, 1).Value))

                If UCase(Trim(SItm.Name)) = strSubject Then

                    With r.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
                        .to = strEmail
                        .cc = ""
                        .bcc = ""
                        .Subject = strSubject

                        .send

                    End With

                   'We have found the email, we can exit the for loop.
                   Exit For
               ElseIf Len(strSubject) < 1 Then
                   'Reached the end. exit loop
                   blnExit = True
               End If
           Next

           If blnExit Then Exit For
        Next

        Set r = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: This did not work: The data is on a separate sheet taking up two columns, with the name of the field in A and the email that the corresponding field should be sent to.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 I've never seen "ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible" before.  What is this?

Comment: How do i attach the images?

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 i cant add images can you send me your email and ill send you the attachments?

Comment: @FrankBall The Envelope visible allows you to see the Excel mail envelope for sending email through excel.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 have added the images, the first one is at the top the second at the bottom. I am trying to loop the code to filter through the pivot fields and send each one to the specific email on the other sheet.

Comment: Sam, I am still having trouble understanding exactly what you want so, I made some assumptions and modified the code above.  I assumed you know the fields name and therefore use that to get the email address (assuming field is fund name).  Please be as descriptive as possible :)

Comment: Okay, so I am working on automating this pivot table so that I can send each filter (fund) to a specific email recipient. The first screenshot shows what the pivot table looks like, and the second is the emails i want to send each fund to. I want to loop this code so that it goes through the fields on the pivot table and sends that specific section to the corresponding email on the separate VBA tab. Does that help? @IAmNerd2000

Comment: Yeah, but without the workbook I cannot test my code. Have a look at the updated code above. I think it may work. What I have done is loop through each field and, using the field name, I loop through the cells on the VBA Tab worksheet to see if the name and subject match. Then, send if they do.

Comment: The fld.currentpage= is not working properly as well as other parts of the code iis there any way I can somehow get this workbook to you to see what is going wrong? @IAmNerd2000

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Added my email to the about me section.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Can you check your email again, the code was rejected when i changed the example to the actual email on the VBA tab.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Is it possible to assign two emails to each fund filter?

Comment: I would just make another row on your vba tab sheet and give it the same name as fund filter but with different email. and repeat for all funds

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 When I try to do this the code stops after the first email listed and does not continue onto the rows i just added. Wondering if there is something in the code that stops it after the first round of emails.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Thanks so much for all of your help!